# Node.js - Simulate a I/O with a sleep

Tags: node.js, nonblocking

My goal is demonstrate the power of a non blocking code with node.js, so I try simulate a I/O event with a sleep statement, but my effort keep failing:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

if( url.parse(request.url).pathname == '/wait' ){
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + 15000);
    response.write('Thanks for waiting!');
}
else{
    response.write('Hello!');
}

response.end();
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Server started');
```

When I access http://localhost:8080/wait after http://localhost:8080, both are waiting for the loop.

Any tips?

Comment: I believe there is something for this at: http://trafficjamapp.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout is your friend, so are braces.

```
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  var doIt, startTime;
  if (request.path === '/wait') {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    doIt = function() {
      if (new Date().getTime() < startTime + 15000) {
        response.write('Thanks for waiting!');
        return setTimeout(doIt, 1000);
      } else {
        return response.end();
      }
    };
    return doIt();
  } else {
    response.write('Hello!');
    return response.end();
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't get it, my goal is get a blocked page (http://localhost:8080/wait) and a page that keeps responding (http://localhost:8080).

Comment: and what is what I did here. see the `setTimeout(doIt, 1000);` in that if statement? What do you think that does?

Comment: When i access localhost:8080/wait with ur code the programe responde immediately and throws an error: Error: write after end
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:413:15) ...

Comment: just updated the code. this works for me. it wont work how you expect it to work unless you use http 1.1 chunked encoding